# What's the maximum amount of time that the UI should be interrupted?

Tags: android, ios, performance, user-interface

I'm making a performance analysis of an app as some parts are very slow, for example it takes 0.310 seconds for a database consult. If I do this in the main thread the UI interruption is very noticeable, the app doesn't feel responsive.

But what is the maximum amount of time you should interrupt the app, what is acceptable?

I want to make it as fast as possible but also don't want to get obsessed and spend hours of work in order to cut the time in a few milliseconds.

Comment: see http://www.nngroup.com/articles/response-times-3-important-limits/

Answer (score 2):

In case of `iOS`, the UI renders at 60fps, so the ideal maximum time would be 1/60 seconds so that the UI doesn't skip a frame. You can work out what performance you need from the minimum fps you want to achieve.

Anyways, make full use of all the tools available at your disposal, like XCode's Time Profiler. etc. Start with the slowest chunks of codes and keep going up.

Answer (score 1):

But what is the maximum amount of time you should interrupt the app, what is acceptable?

### **0**

There is no acceptance level defined as such, it all depends on how good the user-experience you can give. Have background threads/NSOperationQueue/GCD. Only when it's an UI-level operation, use the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

#### In Android

Android will show  you  Triggers ANR

Generally, the system displays an ANR if an application cannot respond to user input. For example, if an application blocks on some I/O operation (frequently a network access) on the UI thread so the system can't process incoming user input events.

see link [ANR](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html#anr)

### No response to an input event (such as key press or screen touch events) within 5 seconds ANR dialog will pop up.